# Defining two functions with the same identifier, one statically and the other externally

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

In C, I defined two functions, with the same identifier, in two different translation units. The first one in the first translation unit is defined with the `static` storage class specifier and the other function is defined with `extern`. I thought, that I will get an error from the linker, but I did not. I am a bit confused. Why did I not get an error from the `ld`?

In the first translation unit:

```
static void func(void){
  return;
}

int main(void){
  func();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the second translation unit:

```
extern int func(int x){
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But in general a static scope variable will hide the global extern and is not an error.

Comment: The symbol defined with `static` cannot be seem outside it's TU.  It won't conflict with other static symbols of the same name, not with one function defined without `static`.

Comment: @kaylum i have already edit the post, including code. thank you for your answer, that make sense.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i have already noticed that, my question was why is that behave? i think the answer from Kaylum make sense

Comment: It behaves like that because the C standard says that's the required behaviour.  (I'm sorry about the typos in my prior comment: "seem" should be "seen", and "not" should be "nor".  Ugh!  My excuse is 'cell phone while walking dog' — not a good excuse, but…)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah okay now it is clear. typos, I fall into them them all the time, not just while walking a dog but also while walking myself LOL. thank you so much for your answer.